# How to run app in Xorg?

Tags: xorg

I installed the Arch Linux and Xorg's packages + `xorg-init` just to test a clear Xorg without some else (I want understand how it works and looks, not for work). And I can run Xorg with XTerm but I don't know how to run some another app for Xorg. Can you explain me, please?
And has it any apps for Xorg without KDE, Gnome, GTK dependencies to I can test it?
P.S. I don't need KDE, GNOME, Xfce or some else DE, and Windows also =) Yeah, I'm noobie but I want learn Xorg to better understand the graphical system in the Linux (where the X Window System ends and the DE begins).

Comment: The only thing you'll learn this way is that X11 itself doesn't have any user interface, most people will need some kind of window manager to do anything useful with it. :) Do try a few WMs though.  DEs is the next level of complexity, and you can avoid _that_.

Comment: Seriously, you are better served by reading a book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101954.do

Comment: I already wrote a simple app for X11 protocol and it works perfect, although I'll install a some window manager, e.g. TinyWM (it's very lite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did on my debian-based machine and you do it yourself

**1) The X server**

First of all you need a X server 
To do so you can use

```
Xnest :n
```

n is the number you want to assign to this display for example

```
Xnest :2
```

> I will keep it simple to understand easily but feel free to look at the manual to have more information

Then you will have a black window. This is the X server waiting for application to run in

[image: Xnest]

**2) Run applications**

Now you can run some application to see what append

First set the display environment variable to *2* or the number you put before. This is to say that we want the application to run on the X server we just created

And then run some apps

```
export DISPLAY=:2
gnome-terminal
xeyes
gparted
```

You will see that they all goes at the same place and you cannot move them but it works :) This is a good start.

[image: some apps]

**3) The window manager**

Ok so why can we move them ? It is because we need a window manager

Let try with a simple one

```
apt-get install twm
```

And now instead of running some apps we will run a window manager witch will handle the window

```
twm
```

now you will see that you can click inside the Xnest window and interact with the window manager. 
You can also run apps and move them :) We are progressing :)

[image: windowManager]

**4) The Desktop Manager**

Now let's try with a Destktop Manager

To do so we will install a simple one. Gnome is kind of complex 
And by this way you will see that we can run two Desktop manager on the same machine

```
apt-get install lxde
```

now run it

```
startlxde
```

You should have a complete Desktop manager running inside the Xnest window :)

[image: DesktopManager]

Comment: here xeyes etc. run in separate window